# AngularJS ngRepeat Watchers Paradox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I pick news from several news sources approx. every 5-10 minutes. I use AngularJS 1.5 and `ng-repeat` works great for several lists of the over 500 news items which I populate to DOM from the server. Trouble is, although I have used `track by` I still have a very high CPU usage whenever I use filters on this lists.

I have tried **bindonce** library i.e. `bindonce ng-repeat` to no noticeable gains. I have also used AngularJS 1.3+ feature `::` which works but after which server updates don't replace the old content because `::` makes the content immutable in the process.

Am wondering is there a way to stop AngularJS watching the lists of item in the ng-repeat UNTIL (this is the caveat) the next time I get new content from the server??

Comment: try with this http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/12/22/exploring-angular-1.3-disabling-debug-info.html

Comment: also keep one time binding for ng-repeat variables not for the list in your case

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. Keep the `::` for one time binding where possible, specially the `ng-repeat` variables.
2. Load the data and keep it in a service.
3. After getting the data, use `$route.reload()` to refresh the controller.

This way you are using onetime binding, but your view will be refreshed with data because the whole controller will be refreshed.